# Shut down akka system with spray from non akka system

Tags: scala, akka, spray

Im very new to akka and futures in scala. Im using spray to get the output of a URL and return a `Future[String]` to another object. Here is the object that is making the HTTP request.

```
object ActionsService {

  private implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher

  val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[String]
  def getActions: Future[String] ={
     val out = getOutput("http://www.google.com")
    out
  }


  def getOutput(url: String): Future[String] ={
    val response = pipeline (Get (url) )
    response
  }

  def shutdown(code: Int): Unit = {
    IO(Http).ask(Http.CloseAll)(1.second).await
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

And here is the main method in the other object where I am trying to shutdown the actor system.

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val test = ActionsService.getActions
test.onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(x)
  case Failure(y) => println(y)
}
  ActionsService.system.shutdown()
```

For some reason the akka system wont shutdown. Ive also tried to shut down the akka system using my shutdown method but I get an `Exception in thread "main" akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out` error (which also occurs in the main method when the shutdown method is called).

akka version is 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above did not end up working for me so I had to block the thread by adding a sleep period for the main method before the shutdown method is called.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val test = ActionsService.getActions
  Thread.sleep(700)
test.onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(x)
  case Failure(y) => println(y)
}
CorporateActionsService.system.shutdown()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify version of Akka you're using but in last version you need to call

```
system.terminate()
```

instead and wait for termination like this (ass an example)

```
Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: akka version is 2.2.3 and I tried   ActionsService.system.awaitTermination() which seemingly never terminates..

Comment: also these methods dont exist in 2.2.3